# Why can't access to enum here?

Tags: c++, class, initialization, member-initialization

Here's my [code/namespace](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8b4ec467ca756bc):

```
namespace myNamespace { 

enum MyType {
    ASD1,
    ASD2,
    ASD3
};

struct MyClass {
    MyType mMyType;

    MyClass(MyType myType = MyType::ASD1) : mMyType(myType) {

    }
};

}
```

Now if I try, within another struct, this code:

```
struct X
{
    myNamespace::MyClass *pMyClass1 = new myNamespace::MyClass(myNamespace::MyType::ASD2);
};
```

it works perfectly, but if I try this:

```
struct X
{
    myNamespace::MyClass mMyClass1(myNamespace::MyType::ASD2);
};
```

it says `'myNamespace::MyType::ASD2' is not a type`.

Since its all declared before, why this?

Comment: Probably something like the compiler understand the second code as a forward declaration of a function

Comment: `myNamespace::MyClass mMyClass1(myNamespace::MyType::ASD2);` is read as a *function* declaration

Comment: Ah, looking at your code sample, the problem is that you're trying to declare a member variable with initializer in a way that you can't do at class scope. Try `int x(3);` - that's also not allowed. Nothing to do with namespaces or `enum`s. At class scope the compiler thinks that's supposed to be a function, not an initialization.

Comment: Use the unified initialization syntax instead `myNamespace::MyClass mMyClass1{myNamespace::MyType::ASD2};`

Comment: Better: use left-to-right initialisation (at least at non-class scopes): `auto mMyClass1 = myNamespace::MyClass{myNamespace::MyType::ASD2};`

Comment: Didn't fail with g++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the brace-or-equal-initializer. You may not use an initializer in parentheses without the sign =.

From the C++ Standard (12.2 Class members)

```
member-declarator:
    declarator virt-specifier-seqopt pure-specifieropt
    declarator brace-or-equal-initializeropt
    identifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt : constant-expression
```

For example

```
myNamespace::MyClass mMyClass1 { myNamespace::MyType::ASD2 };
```

or

```
myNamespace::MyClass mMyClass1 = myNamespace::MyType::ASD2;
```

The last initialization is valid because the constructor is a conversion constructor

Answer (score 5):

Inside class, you might use `{..}` or `= ..` syntax, not `(..)`:

```
struct Test {
    myNamespace::MyClass mMyClass1{myNamespace::MyType::ASD2};
    // myNamespace::MyClass mMyClass1 = myNamespace::MyClass{myNamespace::MyType::ASD2};

};
```